# How does it make sense to rearrange equations like this to find a function

Tags: functions

Like for example I had $\dfrac{(g(x)-1)}{g(x)}=\dfrac x{(x+1)}$ and rearranged to get $g(x)=x+1$ involving multiplying through by $g(x)$.

Clearly $g(x)$ can equal $0$ but it doesn't seem to make sense to me to multiply through by $g(x)$ to get a solution when $g(x)$ can equal $0$ so how does it work and get the right solution. Thanks

edit: Sorry I didn't word this very well. It is the composition of two functions f(x) and g(x) is the solution I showed x/(x+1) which is f(g(x)) however I knew f(x) which was (x-1)/x and needed to find g(x) which is what I was trying to do. So then g(x)=x+1 would satisfy this. And g(-1) would be defined in this case. It is the 4th row down in this image link gyazo.com/adbd45de4445ac8600c6f9695d66fd29

Comment: $\frac{g(x)-1}{g(x)}$  is not defined for $g(x) = 0$.  And hence, for $g(x) = x+1$, $x$ cannot equal $(-1)$, since $g(-1) = -1+1 = 0.$

Comment: If $g (x)=0$ then the LHS is undefined. So the RHS must also be undefined and $x $ must equal $-1$.  That's case 1.  For all other cases $x\ne -1$ and RHS is defined and so $g (x)$ can not be equal to $0$ and  you can multiply by $g (x) $.  That's case 2.  Those are the only two cases.

Comment: The thing is, @fleablood, since the purpose of this question, we are trying to find $g(x)$, which is not defined for $x=-1$.  So the domain excludes it, and hence there can be no $g(-1) = x+1 = 0$.

Comment: Sure there can.  If $g (x)=x+1$ then that statement *is* true.  Even at $x=-1$ the statement is true (albeit meaningless so).

Comment: Andy  Could you add your explanation (which you posted below my answer), within your question post?  (You can copy and paste the comment into your question, after indicating "Additional Info" or "Edit". That may help make your question more clear.  This has been an example of an X-Y Problem...  You are always best off including the context you described to me: original problem, how you proceeded to arrive at the equation you post above, e.g.

Comment: In arriving at the composition $f(g(x)) = \frac x{x+1}$, we have, at this point, $x\neq -1$, else the composition is undefined.

Answer (score 2):

Your solution is partially correct. If someone writes $(g(x)-1)/g(x)=x/(x+1)$, they are assuming $g(x)$ is non-zero and $x\neq -1$, so you must specify the domain has changed for $g$, that is, $g(x)=x+1, x\neq -1$. From an algebraic point of view, you can also just solve this formally.